# django autoconverting datetime property

Tags: python, mysql, django

my datetime property is saving in mysql in this format 2011-03-17 00:00:00 but after fetchind the data with filter function it is giving March 17,2011 midnight but i have not say to do any this type of task. My question is how can i insist django to stic to show same value what is saved in MYSQL.

Answer (score 1):

you'll want to use the datetime format, django's DateTimeField[1] really is a wrapper for datetime.datetime.

in the templates you can use the date[2] filter to apply the format you want for example:

```
{{ item.date|date:"Y-m-d H:i:s" }}
```

This should print out 2011-03-17 00:00:00 in the template. In views use datetimes.strftime[3]

[1] http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#datetimefield

[2] http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/templates/builtins/#date

[3] http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior

Comment: @Madhur,he is just referring to the sources

Comment: @madhur, yep what gladybixly said.

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling your database schema knows this is a date, right? In that case it's not being stored in the format you describe, but as some representation such as seconds since the era.

This means that when you retreave it your code has to do something with it to make it look right. If you don't tell it how to look it'll default to the format you see, but if you use strftime in your python code and a filter in your templates you can make it look however you like, including the original format how you saw it.

Of course the easy way out is to store it in the db as text...

Comment: ok thanks i have done. Now i am sending converted values to client side.

Comment: @Madhur : I'm not quite sure what you mean there, are you having a problem still or has this solved it?